# Ошибка при подключении: "ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol exception"

Tags: база-данных, oracle, аутентификация, oracle12c

Пробую подключить [Grails](https://grails.org/index.html) проект к Oracle БД 12c. Но когда запускаю приложение, то получаю исключение:

> Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException:
>       Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-28040:
>       No matching authentication protocol)

Нашёл предлоаемое решение и попробовал отредактировать .ora файл, но безуспешно.

Добавил следующее в *sqlnet.ora* и пробовал установливать значения `10,11,12`:

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=10
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT=10
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=10
```

, но с никаким из них не заработало.

Может кто-то помочь с этой проблемой?

<sub>Свободный перевод [ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24100117/6571020) от участника [@Aman Adhikari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252814/aman-adhikari)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/24100117

Answer (score 3):

В оф. документации эта [ошибка упомянута в контексте *Oracle RAC*](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/READM/chapter12102.htm#READM266), но решение действительно так же для некластерной БД:

> **Bug 14575666**
>   In 12.1, the default value for the SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION parameter has been updated to 11. This means that database clients using pre-11g JDBC thin drivers cannot authenticate to 12.1 database servers unless the SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION parameter is set to the old default of 8.
>
> This will cause a 10.2.0.5 Oracle RAC database creation using DBCA to fail with the ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol error in 12.1 Oracle ASM and Oracle Grid Infrastructure environments.
>
> **Workaround:**
>   Set SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8 in the $crs_home/network/admin/sqlnet.ora file.

Предложенное решение: установить `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8` на **сервере БД**.

<sub>[В этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26629916) ссылка на фэйк QA, поэтому перенёс только полезный комментарий под ним.</sub>

---

[Комментарий](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100117/ora-28040-no-matching-authentication-protocol-exception#comment75483844_26629916):
Да, в моём случае это решило проблему, но возникла другая: `invalid username/password`, когда пытался подключится в JDeveloper 10 к Oracle БД 12c.

В итоге решил так:

1. `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8`
2. `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES (NONE)`
3. `ALTER SYSTEM SET SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = FALSE`
4. `ALTER USER XY IDENTIFIED BY Pass` (так как меняется регистро-чуствительность)

Answer (score 2):

Удалил **ojdbc14.jar** и установил **ojdbc6.jar** вместо него. У меня заработало.

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26604277) от участника [@Aman Adhikari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252814/aman-adhikari)</sub>

---

Решил проблему установив **ojdbc8.jar** драйвер, он совместим с *Oracle 12c*.

<sub>Похожий [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50981073) от участника [@shardendu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1703937/shardendu)</sub>